# Flutter running new project with the same name as old, shows unidentified developer warning

Tags: flutter, macos, flutter-macos

After updating to macOS Sonoma and Flutter to v3.16, I decided to create a new project with the same name as my previous project that I was working on, on the same Mac machine. Now each time I run it on macOS, it shows the below dialog. How can I get rid of it? I don't want to change my new project's name, package, or bundle.

```
“ape_flutter” is from an unidentified developer and differs from previously opened versions. Are you sure you want to open it?

Opening “ape_flutter” will allow it to access data from previously used versions of “ape_flutter”.
```

[image: warning]

Comment: I have this question, too. My attempts at using 'sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine' haven't worked.